# проблема с нажатием двух клавиш одновременно

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, элементы-управления

Прошу помощи: я не знаю, как повесить событие на несколько одновременно нажатых клавиш. `root.bind('<Клавиша1><Клавиша2>', Функция)` не подходит, поскольку срабатывает только при нажатий клавиш порядке и один раз, даже если прицепить модификатор `KeyPress`. Можно поставить на сочетание с такими клавишами как `shift`, `ctrl`. `alt`, `end` … (их много) , но мне необходимы две клавиши.

Уже есть бинды на все клавиши (1клавиша - 1вызов). Я думал, что нажму две клавиши и будет меня 2 вызова функций, но нет: при нажатие двух клавиш срабатывает лишь событие одной, а соответственно один обработчик. Вот код:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title('tkinter')
c = Canvas(root, height=300, width=400)
c.pack()
body = c.create_rectangle(100, 150, 300, 250, fill='lightblue')

def MoveLeft(event):
    if event.keysym == "a":
        c.move(body, -10, 0)

def MoveRight(event):
    global body
    if event.keysym == "d":
        c.move(body, 10, 0)
    
def MoveUp(event):
    if event.keysym == "w":
        c.move(body, 0, -10)

def MoveDown(event):
    if event.keysym == "s":
        c.move(body, 0, 10)

root.bind('<KeyPress-a>', MoveLeft)
root.bind('<KeyPress-d>', MoveRight)
root.bind('<KeyPress-w>', MoveUp)
root.bind('<KeyPress-s>', MoveDown)
```

Comment: связанный вопрос [tkinter using two keys at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39606019/4279)

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку, но не совсем понятно как это можно использовать в моем коде...

Comment: Спасибо большое за разъяснение, попробую сделать все так как подобает...

Answer (score 1):

Для определения того, что несколько клавиш нажаты одновременно (кроме модификторов, типа `ctrl`, `shift`, `alt`), нужно отслеживать и события нажатия, и отпускания клавиш. Например, если одна клавиша нажата, пока другая еще не отпущена, то они зажаты одновременно.

Ниже пример на основе кода [из ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39609454) пользователя [@dsgdfg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2133240), подправленный для python 3 (с некоторыми модификациями). При зажатии одной или нескольких клавиш одновременно отображается список кодов этих клавиш:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
var = StringVar()
a_label = Label(root, textvariable=var).pack()

pressed_keys = set()


def keyup(event):
    pressed_keys.discard(event.keycode)
    var.set(str(sorted(pressed_keys)))


def keydown(event):
    pressed_keys.add(event.keycode)
    var.set(str(sorted(pressed_keys)))


frame = Frame(root, width=200, height=200)
frame.bind_all("<KeyPress>", keydown)
frame.bind_all("<KeyRelease>", keyup)
frame.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Модифицированный код из вопроса с возможностью управления несколькими зажатыми клавишами (есть проблемы управления при включенной русской раскладке, лучше переделать на использование `keycode` вместо `keysym`, но тогда нужно будет указывать числовые коды клавиш вместо букв):

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

c = Canvas(root, height=300, width=400)
c.pack()
body = c.create_rectangle(100, 150, 300, 250, fill='lightblue')

pressed_keys = set()


def keyup(event):
    print(pressed_keys)
    pressed_keys.discard(event.keysym)


def keydown(event):
    print(pressed_keys)
    pressed_keys.add(event.keysym)


def game_loop():
    # Главный цикл игры, тут делаем все перемещения
    
    # Вычисляем горизонтальную и вертикальную скорость
    # в зависимости то зажатых в данный момент клавиш
    vx = -10 * ("a" in pressed_keys) + 10 * ("d" in pressed_keys)
    vy = -10 * ("w" in pressed_keys) + 10 * ("s" in pressed_keys)
    c.move(body, vx, vy)
    root.after(50, game_loop)


game_loop()

root.bind("<KeyPress>", keydown)
root.bind("<KeyRelease>", keyup)

root.mainloop()
```